# How to make interactive flipcards accessible to screen readers with ARIA?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

My school is using the [W3Schools flip card code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp) for interactivity on our class pages, with some added JavaScript to keep the cards flipped when clicked or tapped. However, I don't think they are accessible for screen readers. It seems like they need some ARIA code, and I am very new to ARIA. How can I make sure students using screen readers can use the flip cards?

I added some ARIA code, but I'm not sure if it's right or useful. Does it make sense that the front side controls the back side and vice versa? I'm also using JavaScript to toggle the aria-expanded between true and false when the cards are flipped.

```
<div class="flip-card">
<div class="flip-card-inner" tabindex="0">
<div class="flip-card-front" role="button" aria-expanded="true" id="flip-card-front_4" aria-controls="flip-card-back_4">
<p>Front of card</p>
</div>
<div class="flip-card-back" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="flip-card-back_4" aria-controls="flip-card-front_4">
<p>Back of card</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need any ARIA, which is good because the [first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1) is to **not** use ARIA if you can help it.

I made two small changes to [the example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card) and it worked with a keyboard and read ok with a screen reader.

I changed

```
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
```

to

```
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner, 
.flip-card:focus .flip-card-inner {
```

so that you'd get the flipping animation on either a mouse hover or a keyboard focus.

I then added `tabindex="0"` to the flip card so that you could <kbd>tab</kbd> to it.

```
<div class="flip-card" tabindex="0">
```

With a screen reader running, when you tab to the flip card, you hear all the text contents in the card.  For [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/), I hear:

*"Avatar  graphic    John Doe  heading    level 1  Architect & Engineer  We love that guy"*

[JAWS](https://www.freedomscientific.com/products/software/jaws/) is similar but marginally different:

*"Avatar John Doe Architect & Engineer We love that guy Graphic"*

It doesn't work that great with Voiceover on iOS.  You can swipe to the image and then double tap to flip it over but it just says "avatar".  But if you keep swiping then you can hear the name and job title.  You just don't know the card flipped when you tapped on it.

The missing usability piece is the *role* of the card.  How does a user know the card is going to flip when it receives keyboard focus?  There isn't a [standard role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) that fits this behavior so you might have to use [`aria-roledescription'](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-roledescription) to give it a decent description.

```
<div class="flip-card" tabindex="0" aria-roledescription="flipping card">
```

Also take a look at this [card design pattern](https://inclusive-components.design/cards/). I'm not sure if he talks about flipping cards but it has some good info.

Comment: Thanks! Should I also keep role="button" since aria-roledescription is supposed to be used with a role? I had included the toggle for aria-expanded since we also have accordions that toggle that way. Since flip cards are not already included in aria like accordions, I'm having a hard time deciding what should be used.

Comment: I was commenting directly on the example code and not your posted code, sorry.  I'm not sure a button role is appropriate because the card doesn't do anything when selected.  The flipping happens when you focus on the card and when you move the focus off (blur). If you change it to only flip when you select it, then a button would be ok.